# Why does my promise finish when ran once but not in a loop?

Tags: node.js, promise

I am doing a project for fun where I am drawing to a canvas in node using pureimage, and then writing each animation frame to a separate png file.

If I run the below code once, it works as expected and creates a single PNG file.

If I put it in a loop, the promise never finishes. I think the existing process is being stopped and restarted because if I stop the program the PNG is corrupt.

So my question is, how can I run multiple promises in a loop, and where can I learn more about this issue?

```
PI.encodePNGToStream(img, fs.createWriteStream('img' + counter + '.png') ).then( function(){

  console.log("Wrote out file")

  counter = counter + 1

  console.log(counter)

}).catch( function() { 

  console.log("Error writing file")

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are adding your code inside the loop, I think you were expecting it to work synchronously, right? But the thing is that promises are asynchronous in nature. The code inside the `then` runs when the promise is resolved.

What you could do is use async/await feature, but you need to wrap it inside a function with an `async` keyword before it like so:

```
async function test() {
    try {
        for(let counter = 1; counter < 10; counter++ ) {
            await PI.encodePNGToStream(img, fs.createWriteStream('img' + counter + '.png') );
            console.log("Wrote out file");
            console.log(counter);
        }
    } catch(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
    }
}
```

Check the following links for further details:

1. https://javascript.info/callbacks
2. https://javascript.info/promise-basics
3. https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: I actually tried this but it still produced the same behavior unless I put about a second delay on it using setTimout. Even considering that it is asynchronous, it should still output the files eventually. However, when I call the code in quick succession, it just never outputs any files or even logs to the console.

Comment: Yes, even if its asynchronous, it should have still output the files. It would be easy if you could share your code or the repo.

Comment: I have created a pull request to your repo. Please have a look at it.
P.S: It is a good practice adding semicolon to each and every statement :)

Comment: Thank you, you solved my problem. Now if only I could make it run faster!